# select max similar rows by numeric field for all users

Tags: mysql, select

we have table as below :

```
  user    point
+-------+------+  
| user1 | 6080 | // user1 has this value  
+-------+------+  
| user1 | 5300 |  
+-------+------+  
| user2 | 6080 | // user2 has this value  
+-------+------+  
| user3 | 6080 | // user3 has this value  
+-------+------+  
| user3 | 5300 |  
+-------+------+  
| user1 | 3520 |  
+-------+------+  
| user2 | 5300 |  
+-------+------+  
| user3 | 9800 |
```

i want to get the max similar value that all `users` have at least one of that
in this sample there are two value that all users have. `6080` and `5300`

result should be `6080`

how can i do that ?

Comment: you should explain what you mean by "max similar value". Do you mean the most frequent value? Otherwise I'd suggest you try `select 6080 as 'result';`

Comment: yes i mean must frequent value. but your suggestion is unusable because i don't know what's that value.

Comment: oh what would life be without the joy of sarcasm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would look like this. You need to limit the results to 1, so for example for mysql you should use limit 1 at the end or for mssql select top 1 point .. etc etc.

```
select point
from user
group by point
having count(*)=(select count(distinct user) from user)
order by point desc
```

Comment: BANG! Perfect, I was right about posting the same.
+1 for being quicker :-)

@Omid: Replace the == by =  SQL doesn't make a syntax difference between comparing and assigning.

Comment: Off topic: I added this question to my favorite, but didn't get notified when this answer came. Isn't this feature enabled?

Comment: @Heiko .. I am with my hands all day in C# .. I do not even think when I put == instead of = @Gunner I have no ideea

Comment: @ Dumitrescu Bogdan: Didi you test your query ?

Comment: @Dumitrescu Bogdan: never mind! I know this issue while switching between languages. @Omid: Don't be afraid to test it yourself. For me the statement looks OK.

Comment: statement returns *nothing*, if there's no point value that every user has got. Correct, isn't it?

Comment: The statement of @Raisen provides lines, as long as there are records in your table. But they might not fulfill your condition (every user must have that max-value)

Comment: i tested it and i'm sure that there is a value that all users got that  still no no result

Comment: i think there is a problem here, query should not return rows that have max value. result should be the max value that has been repeated for all users

Comment: Weird, as the sql is correct and is not a problematic one. Try to see if you really have that value. Do a select count(distinct user) from user and see how many users you have, and after that do a select count(*) from user where point='the value that u know u have'. And see if the results match.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT point, count(*) AS cnt FROM table GROUP BY point ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1
```